# UseState won't trigger useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have 2 functional components that the Parent is passing a state variable a prop to the Child component:

**Parent:**

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [data,setData] = useState()


    const printSomething = async () =>{
       console.log("Use effect called")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        printSomething();
    }, []);


    return (
        <Child setData={setData}/>
    );
}

export default Parent
```

**Child:**

```
const Child = ({setData}) => {

    const doSomething = async () => {
        setData("Data")
    }

   
    return (
    <div className='task-container'>
        <div>
            <button onClick={doSomething}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Child;
```

My question why using `setData()` on the Child component won't trigger `useEffect()` of the Parent component to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `useEffect` will only run its callback when something in its dependency array changes. If the dependency array is empty, it'll only run on mount. Use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    printSomething();
}, [data]);
```

so that it runs whenever `data` changes.

Comment: My dependence array is not empty. But still it runs only on mount.

Comment: Need a MCVE - can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72605749/9515207) to show where you're changing the state?

Comment: I am using a JSON object in useState in the parent component. and I passed it to the child node. and in child note I used useEffect. but it only works on the mount. I tried everything. like JSON stringifying the JSON object but useEffect does not listen. i also posted as a question check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605749/child-component-useeffect-not-triggering-on-props-change?noredirect=1#comment128254130_72605749